# Delegate Control Tutorial/Walk-through

Tags: delegate

Where is a good overview or walk-through of creating delegate controls in SharePoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [this guide by Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/06/using-delegate-control.html) and found it very clear and simple. The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx) is also a reasonable reference.

If you're planning on adding your own delegate controls to a master page or page layout, there is some good advice here from Brendon Schwartz.